Why do header files include themselves?
I am just aware that <strings.h> includes some non-standard string handling functions, compared to <string.h> which holds standard ones. So I check glibc-2.18, and in string/strings.h, there's exactly such content as following:
#include <string/strings.h>

It means that this file includes itself. Why is this so? It doesn't even have Header Guards. Wouldn't it be a big problem if somebody includes this header?
This is not the first time I have encountered this kind of code in glibc. Because I was busy with other things, I didn't pay much attention to it. But now this is too confusing...

Is that line you show cop-pasted? What is the surrounding context? Do you have the line-number and exact location of the file in the glibc-2.18 archive? Perhaps there will be installed multiple strings.h header files, in different locations?

I checked the sourcecode of glibc-2.18 and found a file include/strings.h which contains only the single line shown in the question, and a file string/strings.h with include guard and function declaration. The file include/strings.h with only a single #include does not need an include guard. Adding references to the original source code to the question might clarify if we are talking about the same code or the same files in different locations.

"and in string/strings.h, there's" Is it really string/strings.h where you found this?

@Gerhardh It is not. It's in include/strings.h like I wrote in my answer

@TedLyngmo I have seen that. I wonder if the author just mixed some file names or if he is looking at some different code than we assume.

@Gerhardh Could be, but glibc-2.18 does seem very specific

It is generally consider bad practice to include any form of search path inside an #include - relative or absolute doesn't matter, still bad practice. Folder structure should be handled outside the C source.

It does not appear to be true in this case, but a header file could include itself and conditionally compile the contents differently.

The file include/strings.h in glibc-2.18 has only one line:
#include <string/strings.h>

So include/strings.h includes string/strings.h. They have the same basename, strings.h, but they are in different directories and are two different files. string/strings.h has 139 lines, not 1, and:

strings/strings.h does not #include <string/strings.h>

Unrelated: At some point after glibc-2.18 they reworked this and include/strings.h does not #include <string/strings.h> in glibc-2.29 for example.

See if your compiler has an option to display pre-processor output, so you can see what is actually compiled. Most likely you will find that <string/strings.h> is actually not the same file as strings.h.
I haven’t checked this for strings.h, but my machine has three files for math.h. One that is different per processor, one that is specific to clang, and one specific to Apple, all with the same name, and somehow the pre-processor combines them. So one file would be different for Intel vs Arm vs POWER, one would be different for gcc vs clang, one would be different for windows vs macOS vs Linux.

Using gcc -H lists all the headers that are included.  The OP would see (along with a lot of other lines). /usr/include/strings.h and .. /usr/include/strings/strings.h. (I may have misguessed the number of leading dots, but the second line should have one dot more than the first).
